# Can't replace value in xml in python

Tags: python, xml

I have been trying to figure this out for hours but I can't seem to find the solution. I have the following xml format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><e3r>
<moreData>false</moreData>
<data>
<CashDividend Cusip="" Sedol="" Isin="FR0007052782" TickerCode="" CommonCode="" ExchangeCode="" WPK="" actionID="" Declared_Date="" Ex_Date="" Record_Date="" Pay_Date="" Due_Bill_Redemption_Date="" Confirmation_Date="" Election_Date="" Adjustment_Date="" Net_Amount="" Gross_Amount="" Issuance_Fee="" Tax_Rate_PCT="" Supplemental_Amount="" Tax_Credit="" Foreign_Income="" Franking_PCT="" Percent_of_Par_PCT="" Info_Source="" Type="" Frequency="" Currency="" Amount_Status="" Sequence="" Depositary="" Adjustment_Factor="" Dividend_Note="" Change_Rate_Frequency="" TBA_Flag="" Abnormal_Ex_Date="" Mandatory_Optional="" Status="" Projected_Dividend_Amount="" Stock_Option_DRP="" Reinvestment_Ratio="" Reinvestment_Price="" DRP_Discount_PCT="" EUSD_TID="" EUSD_TID_SW="" Bonus_Amount="" CheckBoxForAdjFact="" AdjustmentFactor="" GrossAmount1="" GrossAmount2="" GrossAmount3="" GrossAmount4="" Currency1="" Currency2="" Currency3="" Currency4="" CashTermsOld="" RightsNew="" RightsOld="" SharesNew="" SharesOld="" SubPeriodFrom="" SubPeriodTo="" TradingFrom="" TradingTo="" RightsBBID="" RightsSECID="" TotalShrsMln="" CashCompId="" CashSecId="" CashTermsNew="" />
<CashDividend Cusip="" Sedol="" Isin="FR0007052782" TickerCode="" CommonCode="" ExchangeCode="" WPK="" actionID="" Declared_Date="" Ex_Date="" Record_Date="" Pay_Date="" Due_Bill_Redemption_Date="" Confirmation_Date="" Election_Date="" Adjustment_Date="" Net_Amount="" Gross_Amount="" Issuance_Fee="" Tax_Rate_PCT="" Supplemental_Amount="" Tax_Credit="" Foreign_Income="" Franking_PCT="" Percent_of_Par_PCT="" Info_Source="" Type="" Frequency="" Currency="" Amount_Status="" Sequence="" Depositary="" Adjustment_Factor="" Dividend_Note="" Change_Rate_Frequency="" TBA_Flag="" Abnormal_Ex_Date="" Mandatory_Optional="" Status="" Projected_Dividend_Amount="" Stock_Option_DRP="" Reinvestment_Ratio="" Reinvestment_Price="" DRP_Discount_PCT="" EUSD_TID="" EUSD_TID_SW="" Bonus_Amount="" CheckBoxForAdjFact="" AdjustmentFactor="" GrossAmount1="" GrossAmount2="" GrossAmount3="" GrossAmount4="" Currency1="" Currency2="" Currency3="" Currency4="" CashTermsOld="" RightsNew="" RightsOld="" SharesNew="" SharesOld="" SubPeriodFrom="" SubPeriodTo="" TradingFrom="" TradingTo="" RightsBBID="" RightsSECID="" TotalShrsMln="" CashCompId="" CashSecId="" CashTermsNew="" />
<CashDividend Cusip="" Sedol="" Isin="FR0007052782" TickerCode="" CommonCode="" ExchangeCode="" WPK="" actionID="" Declared_Date="" Ex_Date="" Record_Date="" Pay_Date="" Due_Bill_Redemption_Date="" Confirmation_Date="" Election_Date="" Adjustment_Date="" Net_Amount="" Gross_Amount="" Issuance_Fee="" Tax_Rate_PCT="" Supplemental_Amount="" Tax_Credit="" Foreign_Income="" Franking_PCT="" Percent_of_Par_PCT="" Info_Source="" Type="" Frequency="" Currency="" Amount_Status="" Sequence="" Depositary="" Adjustment_Factor="" Dividend_Note="" Change_Rate_Frequency="" TBA_Flag="" Abnormal_Ex_Date="" Mandatory_Optional="" Status="" Projected_Dividend_Amount="" Stock_Option_DRP="" Reinvestment_Ratio="" Reinvestment_Price="" DRP_Discount_PCT="" EUSD_TID="" EUSD_TID_SW="" Bonus_Amount="" CheckBoxForAdjFact="" AdjustmentFactor="" GrossAmount1="" GrossAmount2="" GrossAmount3="" GrossAmount4="" Currency1="" Currency2="" Currency3="" Currency4="" CashTermsOld="" RightsNew="" RightsOld="" SharesNew="" SharesOld="" SubPeriodFrom="" SubPeriodTo="" TradingFrom="" TradingTo="" RightsBBID="" RightsSECID="" TotalShrsMln="" CashCompId="" CashSecId="" CashTermsNew="" />
<CashDividend Cusip="" Sedol="" Isin="FR0007052782" TickerCode="" CommonCode="" ExchangeCode="" WPK="" actionID="" Declared_Date="" Ex_Date="" Record_Date="" Pay_Date="" Due_Bill_Redemption_Date="" Confirmation_Date="" Election_Date="" Adjustment_Date="" Net_Amount="" Gross_Amount="" Issuance_Fee="" Tax_Rate_PCT="" Supplemental_Amount="" Tax_Credit="" Foreign_Income="" Franking_PCT="" Percent_of_Par_PCT="" Info_Source="" Type="" Frequency="" Currency="" Amount_Status="" Sequence="" Depositary="" Adjustment_Factor="" Dividend_Note="" Change_Rate_Frequency="" TBA_Flag="" Abnormal_Ex_Date="" Mandatory_Optional="" Status="" Projected_Dividend_Amount="" Stock_Option_DRP="" Reinvestment_Ratio="" Reinvestment_Price="" DRP_Discount_PCT="" EUSD_TID="" EUSD_TID_SW="" Bonus_Amount="" CheckBoxForAdjFact="" AdjustmentFactor="" GrossAmount1="" GrossAmount2="" GrossAmount3="" GrossAmount4="" Currency1="" Currency2="" Currency3="" Currency4="" CashTermsOld="" RightsNew="" RightsOld="" SharesNew="" SharesOld="" SubPeriodFrom="" SubPeriodTo="" TradingFrom="" TradingTo="" RightsBBID="" RightsSECID="" TotalShrsMln="" CashCompId="" CashSecId="" CashTermsNew="" />
</data>
<exs>
<ex e="Information" l="Page: 'Distribution' Regex: '' " m="Page not found in source" i="" t="">
</ex>
</exs>
</e3r>
```

All i want to do is add some value in the field "Cusip". can someone help please.

I have been using the following:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('//lo-dfs/users/username/Desktop/test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

data = root.getchildren()[1]
print data

for child in data:

    child.attrib['Cusip']= "Test"
```

Can someone please assist what I am doing wrong here ?

Thank you

Comment: Do you get an error at all?  Do you ever write the tree back out to disk (I assume you want to store the changes?)

Comment: I don't get any error and yes I do want to store the changes. Can you recommend a way of how to do that ? @mgilson

Comment: Your xml posted  does not seem valid

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I have updated the xml

Comment: You could `for child in root.find("data"): child.set('Cusip',"Test");tree.write('out.xml')`

Answer (score 0):

Locate every `CashDividend` element using, for example [`findall()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.findall), set the attribute value as you are already doing and dump the modified tree to the XML file via [`tree.write()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for cash_dividend in root.findall("CashDividend"):
    cash_dividend.attrib['Cusip']= "Test"

tree.write('test.xml')
```

Works for me.